# Нате вам пожалуйста

Tags: этимология, общие-вопросы, морфология

Интересно услышать мнения, нате это глагол? Откуда фраза?

Answer (score 2):

В целом выражение ***"Нате вам, пожалуйста!"*** - это междометие со значением удивления-разочарования, хотя **частица** "нате" действительно воспринимается как глагол повелительного наклонения в значении "возьмите".

Есть частица "на":

НА, частица. Разг.
Возьми, бери. На, возьми книгу, передай брату. Передай мне масло. - На, дорогой. ◊ Вот тебе (и) на!; Вот те (и) на!
Восклицание по поводу чего-л. неожиданного (обычно неприятного) события, происшествия. На тебе!

НАТЕ, частица. Разг.
1. (при обращении к нескольким, многим лицам или при вежливом обращении, к одному лицу).
Возьмите, берите, получите; на (2.На). Н. билет, путёвку, книгу.
2.
Употр. для выражения удивления, осуждения и т.п. Двадцать лет не курили, а тут н. вам. Попугай молчал и вдруг н. - заговорил! Никогда не выигрывала, а тут н. - пять тысяч! (Грамота.РУ)

Comment: Да какое уж, удивление? "На, вам" - не скажешь. "На, тебе" - можно. "нате вам"- выход из положения. "НА, это все, вам всем" - тоже можно. На междометие не тянет, на глагол больше, но и не частица. Удивление и неожиданность приклеились вместе со словами "Вдруг" и "а тут", запятую бы не забыть: "А тут, нате вам", или просто "нате, приехали". Заполучили, поимели.
 
Частица, это когда на тебе, на вас. Запятую поставил, не частица, а глагол.
"ну, приехали" - ну - междометие. Если не прав, поправьте.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за вопрос, кстати!Всё ещё над ним думаю.Я тоже долго считала  НАТЕ глаголом.Ведь форма множественного числа глаголов повелительного наклонения образуется тоже путём присоединения -ТЕ. Но со словарями спорить трудно, хотя возможно: смотря какой словарь. В словарях НАТЕ - частица и междометие.

Comment: Это несколько другое, это объединение смысла тебе и всем. А по основному - "команда".  
Как и слово ну, типа понукания. Побуждение к действию. Отказ от реакции на которое влечет последствие. А команды -- это глаголы!!! НЕ новая часть речи, но особенная. Ее то в грамматиках и нет. А давно пора бы.

Answer (score 1):

Я так же считаю **нате** глаголом - антонимом слову **дайте**. Во фразе: "Нате вам, пожалуйста!" - подразумевается смысл: получите ситуацию. На мой взгляд, выражение народное, чаще употребляемое женщинами, так как мужчины в таких случаях выражаются более кратко и ёмко (примеры приводить не буду).

Comment: Явот я и говорю, это побуждение к действию, на разбор ситуации, а по сути--команда. ПРедписание, и ожидание ответа на реакцию самого себя, или участников.

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае, слово "на" - глагольного происхождения и отличается от глаголов лишь отсутствием всех форм, кроме повелительного наклонения. Не хуже в этом смысле какого-нибудь глагола "зашибись". Даже применяется в прямом значении (на, Барсик!). "Нате (вам)" (ед. от "вот те на!") сохраняет своё глагольное значение ("получите, извольте видеть"). Пусть себе мучаются составители классификаций.

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае, слово "на" - глагольного происхождения и отличается от глаголов лишь отсутствием всех форм, кроме повелительного наклонения. Не хуже в этом смысле какого-нибудь глагола "зашибись". Даже применяется в прямом значении (на, Барсик!). "Нате (вам)" (ед. от "вот те на!") сохраняет своё глагольное значение ("получите, извольте видеть"). Пусть себе мучаются составители классификаций.